# Adding elements to a 2D vector (Vector of vectors) C++

Tags: c++, vector

So lets say i have the:

```
vector<vector<int> > temp;
```

so it'd just be an empty 2d vector and pretend it's filled with 0s so it'd look like:

```
0  0
0  0
0  0
0  0
```

and let's say I want to add something to that vector, like if I had:

```
int x = 3, y = 4;
```

I want to push these onto the vector so that it looks something like:

```
0  0
0  0
0  0
3  4
```

and I've tried:
`temp.push_back(x,y);` but this isn't the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `temp` has inside a `vector<int>`, the correct syntax would be:

`temp.push_back({x,y});`

Using the brace-initializer list, this creates another vector consisting of two elements, `x` and `y`, and pushes that back onto `temp`.

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked. I am curious though, how would I go about deleting elements? Lets say i have 3 4 on that bottom row then 2 5 on the row above it and i wanted to delete the row 2 5, I'm not sure how deleting will work for a 2d vector.

Comment: That is really a separate question.  You should open another question asking how to delete, since it is not clear if you just want to delete the row before the last, or search for a particular row and delete, etc.